# Stop Gitlab CI/CD from removing venv created by previous job

Tags: gitlab-ci

I have a simple two-job `.gitlab-ci.yml` that looks something like this

```
build:
  script:
    - sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install libgirepository1.0-dev libgtk-3-dev -y
    - python3 -m venv TestEnv
    - pwd
  tags:
    - test

GuiTest:
  stage: test
  before_script:
    - pwd
    - source TestEnv/bin/activate
  dependencies:
    - build
  script:
    - pwd
  tags:
    - test
```

The `build` job runs okay and creates the venv, but it is subsequently deleted by the `GuiTest` job:

```
Reinitialised existing Git repository in /home/gitlab-runner/builds/TEgep27D/0/gitlab-instance-af848a70/testproject/.git/
Checking out d7e4ec16 as detached HEAD (ref is master)...
Removing TestEnv/
```

Why is this happening? And how can I prevent it from happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution `git clean` flags

```
GuiTest:
...
  variables:
    GIT_CLEAN_FLAGS: -ffdx -e TestEnv/
```